# Extracting domains from string fields in layers using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, qgsvectorlayer

I am trying to create a schema and domains for existing shp files. Ultimately I want to use this to create a new file with attribute lists.

In QGIS I have a Python script that extracts the layers, field name, field type, field length and field precision to a CSV file.

I now want to iterate each of the layers and generate a list of unique values to see what values have been entered previously. I will skip the fields that shouldn't contain a list, eg ID numbers.

From the `"String"` fields I wanted to generate a list of unique values, however, I am stuck on an if statement that checks in the field is a string type.

```py
listDomains = {}

for layer in projectLayers:
    for fields in layer.fields():
        if fields.typeName == 'String':
            fieldKey = fields.name()
            fieldValues = list(set(fields.attributes()))
        else:
            continue
        listDomains[fieldKey] = fieldValues
print(listDomains)
```

When I run above, it bypasses the if statement. I have tried a few combination but can't get it. My data is all vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem is you forgot the parentheses after the `typeName()` method. When you call `fields.typeName` what is returned is something like:

```
<built-in method typeName of QgsField object at 0x000002DB4B841C18>
```

Which will *never* evaluate as being equal to `'String'`.

Secondly, `fields.attributes()` will cause an attribute error as the `QgsField` object has no attribute `'attributes()'`. Perhaps you are getting confused with the `attributes()` method of `QgsFeature`.

The `QgsVectorLayer` class actually has a method `uniqueValues()` which takes a field index argument and returns a set containing the unique values in that field so let's use that. Try the code snippet below:

```py
listDomains = {}

for layer in projectLayers:
    for field in layer.fields():
        if field.typeName() == 'String':
            fieldKey = field.name()
            fieldValues = list(layer.uniqueValues(layer.fields().lookupField(field.name())))
        else:
            continue
        listDomains[fieldKey] = fieldValues
print(listDomains)
```